# Как получить предыдущую неделю в moment.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Мне нужно к примеру получить начало недели и конец недели, например: 14.02.2022 00:00 - 20.02.2022 23:59.

У меня получилось вот так:

```
moment().startOf('isoWeek').subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day'), // начало недели
moment().startOf('isoWeek').subtract(1, 'days').endOf('day') // конец недели
```

но почему-то бэк не принимает такое, есть способ получить по другому?

Comment: Что значит "бэк не принимает". В каком формате бэк работает с датами? Как вы данне на бэк отправляете? Или вы сразу пишите на бэке? Какие ошибки показывает бэк?

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("Начала недели -", moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
console.log("Конец недели  -", moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```